# Trying to get data from python-shell, parsing it to an object in nodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I'm having some trouble communicating between nodeJS and Python.

However, the result is not stored. Instead, result is printed before the shell is run. Why is this? How can I store the python output to an object?

Would it be simply better to write a temporary JSON file in my py script?

Here is my code:

```html
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

var result;

  pyshell.PythonShell.run('suggestionWSong.py', null, function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  throw err;
    console.log('hello.py finished.');
    console.log(results[0]);
    result = results[0];
    console.log(result);
  });
  console.log("AA");
  console.log(result);
```

This is my output:

```
AA
undefined
hello.py finished.
{'songs': [{'songName': 'song1New', 'author': 'auth1', 'features': {'bpm': 100, 'key': 'A', 'scale': 'Minor'}}, {'songName': 'song2New', 'author': 'auth2', 'features': {'bpm': 200, 'key': 'B', 'scale': 'Major'}}, {'songName': 'song3New', 'author': 'auth3', 'features': {'bpm': 300, 'key': 'C', 'scale': 'Minor'}}]}       
{'songs': [{'songName': 'song1New', 'author': 'auth1', 'features': {'bpm': 100, 'key': 'A', 'scale': 'Minor'}}, {'songName': 'song2New', 'author': 'auth2', 'features': {'bpm': 200, 'key': 'B', 'scale': 'Major'}}, {'songName': 'song3New', 'author': 'auth3', 'features': {'bpm': 300, 'key': 'C', 'scale': 'Minor'}}]}
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is have a TS function in an electron app call Python. I use tsc to compile my TS into JS, which I then run on Electron. I'm unsure whether I should send the results back to my TS class, or write a JSON file that I can read as needed. This information would be song library data, so I expect 5-10 songs & their features.

Comment: Please either discuss in your question why the link does NOT provide a solution in your case (which is helpful information) or move the answering part into an answer created below. Posting questions which contain answers (100% satisfying or not...) are not appreciated, because they somewhat block the answering of other users.

Comment: I am currently reading the answer, & believe it to be a healthy start - but I am not confident enough to consider it a solution.

Comment: Please do not add links to what might be a solution for others but not for your problem. Lilnk it and discuss your doubt or do not link. Keep in mind [ask]. Please do not get sidetracked. If you find it does NOT help, discuss the detail of your problem which is the reason for it. If it does help turn it into an answer. I expect other solutions will still be added, if there are any. Otherwise please do not confuse things with irrelevant "maybe" links.

Comment: It was more more to see if I was going the right direction. Luckily someone answered my question and I now feel comfortable adding that link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `pyshell.PythonShell.run` is an asynchronus function.
meaning it takes time to execute so instead of waiting for it your script will execute any code below it

so it is like doing this

```
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

var result;
console.log("AA");
console.log(result);

  pyshell.PythonShell.run('suggestionWSong.py', null, function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  throw err;
    console.log('hello.py finished.');
    console.log(results[0]);
    result = results[0];
    console.log(result);
  });
```

You need to tell the script to wait for the function to execute
or run anything you want in the callback function but take care to not fall in [Callback Hell](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/callback-hell/#:%7E:text=Callback%20Hell%2C%20also%20known%20as,a%20few%20callbacks%20seem%20harmless.)

take a look at promises or at [async await](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp) syntax

you need to do something like this:

```
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

var result;




let myPromise = new Promise((reject, resolve)=>{

pyshell.PythonShell.run('suggestionWSong.py', null, function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  reject(err);
    else {
      console.log('hello.py finished.');
      resolve(results);
}
 });

});
  
result = await myPromise
console.log("AA");
console.log(result);
```

note: normally you need an async function to use `await` but in the latest version of node you can use it like I did

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this out and add the other link as an answer  per Yunnosch' request. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the recommendation given to me by White Death. I could not get his await working for some reason. In any case, the following alternative worked for me.

```html
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');
var result;

test();

async function test(){
  result = await go();
  console.log("AA");
  console.log(result);

}

async function go(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    pyshell.PythonShell.run('suggestionWSong.py', null, function  (err, results)  {
        if  (err){
          console.log('fail');
          reject(err);
        }  
        else {
          console.log('hello.py finished.');
          console.log(results[0]);
          resolve(results[0]);
    }
     });
    
  });
  
}
```

> hello.py finished.

> {'songs': [{'songName': 'song1New', 'author': 'auth1', 'features': {'bpm': 100, 'key': 'A', 'scale': 'Minor'}}, {'songName': 'song2New', 'author': 'auth2', 'features': {'bpm': 200, 'key': 'B', 'scale': 'Major'}}, {'songName': 'song3New', 'author': 'auth3', 'features': {'bpm': 300, 'key': 'C', 'scale': 'Minor'}}]}

> AA

> {'songs': [{'songName': 'song1New', 'author': 'auth1', 'features': {'bpm': 100, 'key': 'A', 'scale': 'Minor'}}, {'songName': 'song2New', 'author': 'auth2', 'features': {'bpm': 200, 'key': 'B', 'scale': 'Major'}}, {'songName': 'song3New', 'author': 'auth3', 'features': {'bpm': 300, 'key': 'C', 'scale': 'Minor'}}]}